# Append element to parent and position based on parent's current width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cookies

I have a progress bar that indicates the scroll progress for a page. So if I scroll the page half way down the progress bar width is set to 50%, so it is constantly changing based on where I am on the page.

```
(function(){
    var $w = $(window);
    var $prog = $('.progress-bar');

    var wh, h, sHeight;

    function setSizes(){
        wh = $w.height();
        h = $('#page-content-wrapper').height();
        sHeight = h - wh;
    }

    setSizes();

    $w.on('scroll', function(){
        var perc = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, $w.scrollTop()/sHeight));
        updateProgress(perc);
    }).on('resize', function(){
        setSizes();
        $w.trigger('scroll');
    });

    function updateProgress(perc){
        $prog.css({width : perc*100 + '%'});
    }

}());
```

What I would like to do is append an element to visually indicate the bookmarked position in relation to the progress bar. So let's say I want to add an asterix (*) below the progress bar when I click the bookmark button/link.

To do this I need a way of using the current progress bar width and use that to set the appended element position, which I have, though not sure how to apply that in append context.

```
$('#bookmark').on("click", function() { 
    $(".progress-bar").append("<div style='position:absolute; left:xxxx%'>*</div>");
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote you code:

```
var w = $(window);
var prog = $('.progress-bar');
var wh, h, sHeight;

function setSizes() {
    wh = w.height();
    h = $('.text')
        .height();
    sHeight = h - wh;
}
setSizes();
w.on('scroll', function () {
        var perc = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, w.scrollTop() / sHeight));
        updateProgress(perc);
    })
    .on('resize', function () {
        setSizes();
        w.trigger('scroll');
    });

function updateProgress(perc) {
    prog.css({
        width: parseInt(perc * 100, 10) + '%'
    });
    if (perc <= 0) $('#c')
        .hide();
    else $('#c')
        .show(500);
}
$('#c')
    .hide();
$('#c')
    .click(function () {
        $('.star')
            .remove();
    });
$('.bk')
    .click(function () {
        var add = "";
        l = prog.width() - 10;
        t = prog.height() / 2;
        add = "<div class=\"star\" style=\" left:";
        add += l;
        add += "px; top:";
        add += t;
        add += "px;\">*</div>";
        $('body')
            .append(add);
    });
```

[**Demo JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tegos/7qbph0mu/)

Comment: Exceptional work. Thank you very much Tegos. I hope all is well in Ukraine.

Answer (score 0):

You are using double quotes inside the double quotes in append()

It should be like this,

```
$(".progress-bar").append("<div style='position:absolute; left:xxxx%'>*</div>");
```

Comment: Thanks - though that's not my issue.

Comment: Please check wether you are able to capture #bookmark click event properly by using alert or console.log()...

Comment: What I need is to dynamically set the left position according to the progress bar width.